# Implementing SQL-like order in C++

Tags: c++

Is there an algorithm in c++ to sort by multiple columns? Or some other way like SQL does it in a very simple way, `ORDER BY <>,<>`? For example, given SQL SillyData table:

```
Name   Age  FavouriteFruet LuckyNumber
--------------------------------------
Mary   22   Apple          2
Alice  22   Banana         7
Bob    21   Orange         8
Mark   21   Apple          0
John   22   Banana         3
```

When I do 
`SELECT * FROM SillyData ORDER BY Age, FavouriteFruet, LuckyNumber` this yeilds the result:

```
Name   Age  FavouriteFruet LuckyNumber
--------------------------------------
Mark   21   Apple          0
Bob    21   Orange         8
Mary   22   Apple          2
John   22   Banana         3
Alice  22   Banana         7
```

All I can think of is a `list` of `tuple`s. But then I would have to sort by first `tuple` type, lock the order of it, then second, ...and so on. Looks complicated and cumbersome. Any better way?

Comment: How is your data now currently stored?

Comment: You should look into [`std::stable_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) which essentially does this. Sort by __, then by ___, then by ___, and so on.

Comment: @RvdK Usually In a SQL table, but I can have it in any c++ container. In this example it even can be static. The data is just for the sake of question

Comment: @ CoryKramer Thank you! I'll have a look

Comment: I would write a Container designed for the data to be used with the mentioned suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming that you want a case-insensitive compare for the strings, this is a starting point:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <functional>

struct row
{
    std::string Name;
    int Age;
    std::string FavouriteFruet;
    int LuckyNumber;
};

auto index_order(const row& r)
{
    auto as_upper = [](std::string s)
    {
        std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), [](auto c){return std::toupper(c); });
        return s;
    };
    return std::make_tuple(std::cref(r.Age), as_upper(r.FavouriteFruet), std::cref(r.LuckyNumber), as_upper(r.Name));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<row> results =
    {
        { "Mary", 22, "Apple", 2},
        { "Alice", 22, "Banana", 7},
        { "Bob", 21, "Orange", 8},
        { "Mark", 21, "Apple", 0},
        { "John", 22, "Banana", 3},
    };

    std::sort(results.begin(), results.end(),
              [](auto const& l, auto const& r)
              {
                  return index_order(l) < index_order(r);
              });

    for (auto const& r : results)
    {
        std::cout << r.Name << " | " << r.Age << " | " << r.FavouriteFruet << " | " << r.LuckyNumber << '\n';
    }    
}
```

expected output:

```
Mark | 21 | Apple | 0
Bob | 21 | Orange | 8
Mary | 22 | Apple | 2
John | 22 | Banana | 3
Alice | 22 | Banana | 7
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! I didn't think that `tuple<>` < `tuple<>` compared all it types! Does it?

Comment: Also, why wouldn't it work with case-sensitive strings too?

Comment: @adiamond yes, tuples have full support for lexicographical comparisons. Bear in mind that std::string is case-sensitive, using ascii (usually) ordering. In that scheme, 'A' comes before 'a' and 'Z' comes before 'a'.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much, it's an excellent starting point !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [std::stable_sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) for this. For example I have defined different individual sort functions for type `info` and use them with [std::stable_sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) to achieve any relative ordering I desire:

```
struct info
{
    std::string name;
    int age;
    std::string fav_fruit;
    int fav_number;

    // static functions define sorting methods
    static bool sort_by_name(info const& lhs, info const& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.name < rhs.name;
    }

    static bool sort_by_age(info const& lhs, info const& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.age < rhs.age;
    }

    static bool sort_by_fav_fruit(info const& lhs, info const& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.fav_fruit < rhs.fav_fruit;
    }

    static bool sort_by_fav_number(info const& lhs, info const& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.fav_number < rhs.fav_number;
    }

    // friend function provides output operator
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, info const& i)
    {
        return os << i.name << '\t' << i.age << '\t' << i.fav_fruit << '\t' << i.fav_number;
    }
};

int main()
{

    std::vector<info> infos
    {
        {"Mary",  22, "Apple",  2},
        {"Alice", 22, "Banana", 7},
        {"Bob",   21, "Orange", 8},
        {"Mark",  21, "Apple",  0},
        {"John",  22, "Banana", 3},
    };

    // std::stable_sort will not rearrange the currently sorted order
    // of items that are otherwise considered equal in terms of the current
    // sort condition

    // NOTE: We sort them in reverse order of importance, the most significant
    // ordering being the last one imposed

    std::stable_sort(infos.begin(), infos.end(), info::sort_by_fav_number);
    std::stable_sort(infos.begin(), infos.end(), info::sort_by_fav_fruit);
    std::stable_sort(infos.begin(), infos.end(), info::sort_by_age);

    std::cout << "Name\tAge\tFruit\tNumber" << '\n';
    std::cout << "----\t---\t-----\t------" << '\n';

    for(auto i: infos)
        std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
Name    Age Fruit   Number
----    --- -----   ------
Mark    21  Apple   0
Bob     21  Orange  8
Mary    22  Apple   2
John    22  Banana  3
Alice   22  Banana  7
```

Comment: Stable sort is a nice idea. I have a feeling that multiple stable sort passes might be less efficient than a single sort based on the entire computed index. What do you think?

Comment: @RichardHodges Probably, but I think this method makes for easy programmatic control. Your user can select the individual sorts and the order to perform them. So I think it depends on what your needs are. (That's why I added this answer despite yours being a good answer).

Comment: @Galik I guess it is a good approach for a dynamic control over this structure. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @adiamond Absolutely. For example a `GUI` can offer the sort types in a list to be selected and they can be applied in the selected order. Or that can be hidden and the `GUI` user just clicks on a table's column heading to re-sort the table by that column (keeping the other ordering in-tact).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want some [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

So use [std::lexicographical_compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare) probably passed to some [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) as the compare test.

<sup>(I hope that you are using C++11 at least)</sup>